# xmpp server and roster issue

Tags: iphone, xmpp, ejabberd

I am working on the jabber chatting Applications with the use of XMPP server .
I want to make 2 user friend so I have to add roster with the use of mysql query.
I have make entry in two tables.(1) ofRoster (2)ofRosterGroups.
I make entry in both the table but its not working.

Is there anything where I am missing.
I can do this with the admin panel but i don't want to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using openfire (those tables in SQL look like the openfire setup).  If so, the table you have to edit is "ofGroupUser".  To add a user to a group you need to do a sql insert into that table where the group name is the group you want to add the user to, the username is the user you are adding to the group and administrator is the flag of that user's authority (just use 0).  An example insert would look like this:

INSERT INTO ofGroupUser VALUES("group name", "user", administrator);

However, as mentioned in the above post this is not a good method for doing this as it will not immediately affect the server.  You must restart the server for these changes to take place because openfire (or whatever server you are using) probably only reads the database on start up.  Once it caches everything, it will edit the database according to requests (like adding users or groups through the admin console), but will not read from it and your additions will not be seen until a server restart occurs.

Basically, doing manual sql inserts will produce the desired results, and, if you are just testing some functionality, will work just fine as long as you restart the server.  If you are using openfire and need to do group administrative work in some way besides the web ui, I would look into using a different server.  As far as I know, openfire isn't real great with administration outside of it's web ui.  [Here](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/servers/) is a list of many open source xmpp servers.  I'd recommend [ejabberd](http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/) (as mentioned above post) it has a very nice control tool called ejabberdctl with an available expansion module called mod_ctlextra ([here is the man page for it which lists commands](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man8/ejabberdctl.8.html)) that will allow you to do what I assume you are wanting.  Then you don't have to worry about sql and restarting, just use their tool which is how it should be.

Also, on a side note, ejabberd is extremely efficient due to the nature of the language used to write it:  [Erlang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_%28programming_language%29). Great stuff.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you are using the odbc modules with ejabberd. The sql schema though defines two tables `rostergroups` and `rosterusers`, not the ones you mention in the question. In any case you should **not** update the tables directly, ejabberd keeps internal state and does not get notified of your changes.

The way to go is by actually having the users send the mutual subscriptions and accept them as per the [rfc](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3921.html). [Roster Item Exchange](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0144.html) might also be useful.